# Is the graph that is attached (a form of the arrhenius equation) only used when the temperature is varied?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

[image]

[image]
determine the approximate value of Ea with its appropriate units.

[image]
In my lab course, I am doing an experiment on the rate of reaction, but all three of my trials were using the same temperature. That would just result in a straight vertical line, correct?

EDIT: It was brought to my attention that I would have to use varying temperatures for this form of graph. I will be using a similar form of the example shown, but I'll be using log instead of ln which can be seen in problem 6. Would this result in a positive slope? Am I able to estimate the activation energy of all 3 parts or
just the activation energy overall, and how do I go about doing it?

Comment: That would be no use.

Comment: You see that the plot varies $T$ (expressed as $1/T$) and running the experiments at one temperature only leaves you in an underdetermined situation where you access only one of the red dots. Without accessing the other red dots about the reaction run at other temperatures, you don't access the slope (even less than «a straight vertical line»).  Keep in mind that the approach *assumes* the reaction to proceed by the same mechanism for all the temperatures varied; a significant deviation from the straight line should ring a bell.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I estimate the Ea(s) for the graph?